# SQL How do I update a single row with the first match from multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables to reference in an update statement. I need to move certain details from Table3 to Table1. But there is no ID reference between the two. The PK in Table3 matches the PK in Table2. I need to link based on two conditions. ColumnY from Table2 to PK of Table1 and on specific text found in ColumnP of Table 2. The last portion is where I'm getting stuck. I only need to copy the first matching row found in Table3 to add to Table1.

The script I wrote comes back with an error "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row". I haven't been able to figure out how to copy the first row only. I'm looking to return the first matching row only as there aren't many duplicates and can modify manually afterwards. Unless there is a way to exclude the duplicates which also can work.

This is what I've used as a base.

```
UPDATE Table1
    SET Table1.ColumnG = (
        SELECT Table3.ColumnH
        FROM 
        Table3,
        Table2
        WHERE Table3.ID = Table2.ID
        and Table2.ColumnY = Table1.ID
        and Table2.ColumnP = 'DETAIL'
);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will have a better experience here if you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62458407/edit) your question with the details needed to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Specifically, the relevant parts of the table structures, your attempt so far, sample data, and a mock up of your desired results would help us help you.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I miss-understand part of that. I'll update with some code.

Comment: What do you consider "the first row only"? Just pick one matching row arbitrarily? Then just take a value with `MIN` or `MAX`: `UPDATE Table1 SET Table1.ColumnG = (SELECT MAX(Table3.ColumnH) ...` or `UPDATE Table1 SET Table1.ColumnG = (SELECT MIN(Table3.ColumnH) ...`.

Comment: You are using a join syntax that was used in the 1980s, before the SQL standard introduced explicit joins (in 1992). Don't do that. This is year 2020; use proper joins: `FROM table3 INNER JOIN table2 ON table3.id = table2.id`.

Comment: You haven't answered my question. What do you consider "the first row only"?

Comment: Apologies @ThorstenKettner, the first row isn't necessarily what I'm looking for I guess. It's the first match actually. I have the same record listed more than once but only need one of the many that can be present (up to ~5 ). Reviewing older similar posts it referenced the first row many times so I may have used the wrong terminology. The objective is to move all the data from one table to another but in some cases. Table2 has many matching rows to Table1's single row entry.

Comment: As mentioned, if there can be multiple values and you don't care which, just use `MIN` or `MAX` or add `AND rownum = 1` to your conditions.

Comment: Thank you @ThorstenKettner I did try the `AND rownum = 1` and I was able to update all but a handful which for some reason it could not copy. They should have been a 1-1 match as the database only contains one entry in all the tables.

Comment: Also, if I try and use this on a different column within the same tables (I have a total of three to move over) it says it's updating but the new column remains blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    UPDATE Table1
    SET Table1.ColumnG = 
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT Table3.ColumnH
        FROM 
        Table3,
        Table2
        WHERE Table3.ID = Table2.ID
        AND Table2.ColumnY = Table1.ID
        AND Table2.ColumnP = 'DETAIL'
    ) WHERE rownum <= 1
);
```

Comment: For Oracle that would be `fetch first row only`.

Comment: I've updated my questions with some code. I've never used the fetch first row only. I'll check that out. But would it apply to where I'm placing it?

Comment: You don't need the additional subquery. And you are missing a parenthesis before `SELECT`. `UPDATE Table1 SET Table1.ColumnG = (SELECT Table3.ColumnH ... WHERE rownum = 1)` or `UPDATE Table1 SET Table1.ColumnG = (SELECT Table3.ColumnH ... FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY)`, with the latter only being available as of Oracle 12c. `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` is standard SQL and hence the preferred way of limiting rows, if your Oracle version features it.

Comment: Thanks @ThorstenKettner but there is no direct link between table1 and table3. The database is version 11 and is 32 bit.

Comment: @Chris, the code didn't work as expected. It only updated one record in the table.